# Packages used in this image?

Tags: listings, sourcecode

Does somebody know which packages were used to create the following homework assignment? I would like to insert Java source code in exactly the same way in my `.tex` files

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Looks like the `listings` package has been used

Comment: `minted` could be an alternative

Answer (score 6):

A small starter trial (there are many, many options for `listings`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}

\lstset{language=Java,frame=single,numbers=left,keywordstyle={\color{magenta}\bfseries},basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},commentstyle=\color{blue},showstringspaces=false}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\texttt{\bfseries Hello}} 

\texttt{Hello}

\begin{lstlisting}
public class HelloWorld{

/*
 Some comment
*/

  public void printHelloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a bold courier version:

Since `\ttfamily` is used there is no `bold` font for this in the normal setup of `Computer Modern` fonts. If `\ttdefault` is changed to `pcr` (courier) there is a bold version of type writer like font. Additionally, `\bfseries` for the `keywordstyle` has to be appended too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}  % Change `\ttfamily` to use courier font

\lstset{language=Java,frame=single,numbers=left,keywordstyle={\color{magenta}\bfseries},basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},commentstyle=\color{blue},showstringspaces=false}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\texttt{\bfseries Hello}} 

\texttt{Hello}

\begin{lstlisting}
public class HelloWorld{

/*
 Some comment
*/

  public void printHelloWorld() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Christian, how can I change the fonts? I want to use Courier

Comment: See the update: Use `\basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}` for example

Comment: Does a list with all possible colors exist somewhere? I want to change the keyword color from pink to purple, for instance.

Comment: @PrimeCuts: Of course, see [xcolor](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) for example, but this not part of your question.

Comment: A last question on this topic: Can I set just the keywords in bold by default? Is this possible?

Comment: @PrimeCuts: See the update again, at the lower half, without screen shot however